# Is it possible to define the boolean value of an arbitrary object?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in JavaScript to pre-specify the boolean value that an arbitrary object should have?

For example, suppose I define

```
function NIL () {
    this.car = this.cdr = this;
}

var nil = new NIL;
```

I would like to have `!nil` evaluate to `true`.  Is this possible in JS?

(P.S.: I'd hoped that defining a method like `toBoolean`, by analogy with `toString`, would do the trick, but this did not work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for conversion to boolean are fixed by the [ECMAscript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9), so you cannot do that. You should use your own functions to perform your checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work - sort of, by overriding "valueOf":

```
NIL.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    return false;
};
```

It won't make `!nil == true` but it will make `nil == false`.

But since this behavior is inconsistent, I agree with other answers - you should use your own functions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use functional programming way to define a customize typing system. I am not sure whether this is what you need, but you this does what you described

```
function NIL () {
    this.car = this.cdr = this;
    this.isNull = function(){
        return false;
    }
}

var nil = new NIL();
console.log(!nil.isNull()) // true
```